# What Dutch authority can certify my personal details for German agency?

Tags: netherlands, german-citizens, criminal-records, certification

I am a German resident of the Netherlands and need to request a German “erweitertes Führungszeugnis” (extended certificate of good conduct) for helping with a summer camp in Germany. (The organizers explicitly requested the eFZ in a way that the Dutch “Verklaring Omtrent het Gedrag” is not in the scope of this question.)

On [the corresponding request form](https://www.bundesjustizamt.de/DE/SharedDocs/Publikationen/BZR/antrag_en.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=12), to be sent to the Bundesamt für Justiz, *“The personal details and the signature must be
officially certified. Such official certification, which must be of a recent date, can be issued by a German
diplomatic or consular representation, by a **foreign authority**, or by a notary public.”* (emphasis mine, from the Notes page of the form.)

The personal details requested on the form are implicitly the personal home address, and explicitly listed under “my personal details are” the surname at birth, surname, first name(s), date of birth, place of birth and nationality – which are all available in my passport.

What Dutch authority is able to officially certify my personal details and signature on a the form to the German Bundesamt für Justiz?

Answer (score 4):

I went to my Dutch municipality and requested a “Legitimatie Handtekening”, which is one of the standard tasks they do, on the request form. The Dutch stamp is very large compared to the space reserved for it on the form, but it was accepted without issues by the Bundesamt für Justiz and I received my eFZ.